Calling SSRS Report from SSIS
I am trying to call a SSRS report via SSIS using the solution found here:https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3475/execute-a-sql-server-reporting-services-report-from-integration-services-package/
I the script runs without error but creates a blank (4kb) Excel file. The parameters match those found in the RDL, however, ServiceArea, Location are integer values in the SQL DB. Could my issue be the data types?
Imports System
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Math
Imports Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime
Imports System.ComponentModel
Imports System.Diagnostics
<Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.SSISScriptTaskEntryPointAttribute()>
<System.CLSCompliantAttribute(False)>
Partial Public Class ScriptMain
    Inherits Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.VSTARTScriptObjectModelBase
    Enum ScriptResults
        Success = Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DTSExecResult.Success
        Failure = Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DTSExecResult.Failure
    End Enum
    Protected Sub SaveFile(ByVal url As String, ByVal localpath As String)
        Dim loRequest As System.Net.HttpWebRequest
        Dim loResponse As System.Net.HttpWebResponse
        Dim loResponseStream As System.IO.Stream
        Dim loFileStream As New System.IO.FileStream(localpath, System.IO.FileMode.Create, System.IO.FileAccess.Write)
        Dim laBytes(256) As Byte
        Dim liCount As Integer = 1
        Try
            loRequest = CType(System.Net.WebRequest.Create(url), System.Net.HttpWebRequest)
            loRequest.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials
            loRequest.Timeout = 600000
            loRequest.Method = "GET"
            loResponse = CType(loRequest.GetResponse, System.Net.HttpWebResponse)
            loResponseStream = loResponse.GetResponseStream
            Do While liCount > 0
                liCount = loResponseStream.Read(laBytes, 0, 256)
                loFileStream.Write(laBytes, 0, liCount)
            Loop
            loFileStream.Flush()
            loFileStream.Close()
        Catch ex As Exception
        End Try
    End Sub
    Public Sub Main()
        Dim url, destination As String
        destination = Dts.Variables("Folder_Destination").Value.ToString + "\" + "Report_" + Dts.Variables("Location").Value.ToString + "_" + Format(Now, "yyyyMMdd") + ".xls"
        url = "https://websiteURLt&rs:Command=Render&Location=" + Dts.Variables("Location").Value.ToString + "&ServiceArea=" + Dts.Variables("ServiceArea").Value.ToString + "&StartDate=" + Dts.Variables("START_DATE").Value.ToString + "&EndDate=" + Dts.Variables("END_DATE").Value.ToString + "&DateType=" + Dts.Variables("DateType").Value.ToString + "&rs:Format=EXCEL"
        SaveFile(url, destination)
        Dts.TaskResult = ScriptResults.Success
    End Sub
End Class

The variables in the SSIS package are defined as STRING, Date/Time, and INT64 respectively.

What does the URL look like once it's been generated? I would inspect theURL and try copy/pasting into your browser to see if it works there before I looked any further.

" the script runs without error" -- sounds like you need to do some debugging. Have you tried dropping a break point and debugging the script? Inspect each line and verify it's giving the result you expect.

https://company.org/reports/report/Quality/QUA_10180%20-%20Coded%20Patient%20Safety%20Indicatorst&rs:Command=Render&Location=90009008&ServiceArea=9000&StartDate=1/1/2024&EndDate=2/1/2024&DateType=2&rs:Format=EXCEL
This is the URL that is generated and it throws the 260 character error. It's less than 260 characters. I'm guessing the format is incorrect?

It might be the path in the URL that is wrong. your URL is in the form https://myServer/reports which is the default address of the web portal but you probably need to use the web service url which by default is https://myServer/reportserver . You can check the actual address by looking at the web service url setting in SSRS Configuration Manager.

Alan - you are the man. You were 100% correct - this worked for me!

Alan was correct - thank you!!
https://companyURL.com/ReportServer/Pages/ReportViewer.aspx%2fQuality%2fQUA_10180&rs:Command=Render&Location=90009011&ServiceArea=9000&StartDate=1/1/2024&EndDate=2/1/2024&DateType=2
